# Can't place date strings in data frame that is coming from CSV

Tags: r, csv, date

I am pulling a date with class `<chr>` format out of a data frame that is loaded from a CSV. 
I can remove and manipulate it to a date with class `<date>` and format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
When I go to place it back in the df it turns it to an excel date.

I can pull the excel (class `<chr>`) out and manipulate into the previous format with `as.Date(as.numeric(x), orgin = '1970-01-01')` Just can't get it in the df with the correct format.

I tried to create a reproducible example, but this seems only to be the case when loading CSV files. See code below. I think it shows the issues as clear as I can think of without the actual CSV file.

```
#pulling it out 
> l <- CL.Spend[1,]
> 
> l
  ï..Apparatus.Contractor.Services..LLC        X      X.1
4                                       Sep 2018 Oct 2018
       X.2      X.3      X.4      X.5      X.6      X.7
4 Nov 2018 Dec 2018 Jan 2019 Feb 2019 Mar 2019 Apr 2019
       X.8      X.9     X.10     X.11           X.12
4 May 2019 Jun 2019 Jul 2019 Aug 2019 Sep 1-18, 2019
> #manipulating it
> x <- as.Date(gsub(' ','-01-',l), '%b-%d-%Y')
> #testing 
> x
 [1] NA           "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01" "2018-11-01"
 [5] "2018-12-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01"
 [9] "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01" "2019-06-01" "2019-07-01"
[13] "2019-08-01" "0001-09-01"
> #replacing 
> CL.Spend[1,] <- x
> print(CL.Spend[1,])
  ï..Apparatus.Contractor.Services..LLC     X   X.1   X.2
4                                  <NA> 17775 17805 17836
    X.3   X.4   X.5   X.6   X.7   X.8   X.9  X.10  X.11
4 17866 17897 17928 17956 17987 18017 18048 18078 18109
     X.12
4 -718919
```

Comment: Each column of a data frame can only be one class.  Mostly likely all of columns of your dataframe are character type since they came from a csv file.  So when you attempt to replace the first row with the dates (ie hidden integers) are convert back into character objects. I not sure what your goals are, therefore I can't provide  any recommendations or work arounds.

Comment: @DaveT Thanks! the goal is to have that row in class <date>, There are two values so if rows and columns are swapped that would work too.

Comment: Yes, if you transpose the dataframe and make the first column the dates and the second column the data that would be good solution.